# Stop htaccess detecting folders as such and instead use RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I stop .htaccess detecting folders as such and instead use a RewriteRule?

I have tried everything I found!

This is my current .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks

DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

#Block direct access to root php files
RewriteRule ^(init|404|_header|_footer|home)\.php$ index.php?error [L]

#Get doc
RewriteRule ^docs/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?doc=$1 [L]

#Get release
RewriteRule ^releases/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?release=$1 [L]

#Get page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

**Notes:**

- I have the folders `docs`, `releases` and `pages` in server.
- I want to give 404 errors to ALL PHP files, but index.php on root.

**The issues:**

- `site.com` (without trailing slash) throws 403 error, also because of `Options -Indexes`, but if I remove it, It shows the folder instead of loading the default page.
- If I remove `DirectorySlash Off` it solves the previous issue but then when I go to the links that match folders, it ignores the RewriteRules and then appends its query strings (eg. `site.com/docs/?page=docs`). Of course, it shows the correct page I want, but still, that link bugs me.

How can I do this?

Btw, I had also to add the first RewriteRule to avoid direct access of PHP files in root. Is there a way to do it dynamically, without to list the files to block? I tried `deny`, even with exclusions to CSS, JS and images, but I get unexpected results.
I want to give 404 errors to ALL PHP files, but index.php on root.

Answer (score 0):

Your full .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
DirectorySlash On

RewriteEngine On

#Block direct access to root php files
RewriteRule ^(init|404|_header|_footer|home)\.php$ index.php?error [L]

RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]

#Get doc
RewriteRule ^docs/(.*)$ index.php?doc=$1 [L]

#Get release
RewriteRule ^releases/(.*)$ index.php?release=$1 [L]

#Get page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Still doesn't solve my first issue. I'm still getting 403 error on `site.com` without trailing slash.

Comment: Still no, sorry. It solves the first issue, but then gives 403 on `site.com/docs`, `site.com/releases` and `site.com/pages`, and also 404 on all subpages of these links, in other words, the second and third RewriteRules don't work anymore.

Comment: Isn't `site.com/pages` being redirected to `site.com/pages/` since I have `DirectorySlash On` now?

Comment: Yes, it is, but I guess that `Option -Indexes` gets priority over the RewriteRule and still blocks the access to the page.

Comment: This time, folders get 404 error. I guess that RewriteRules aren't the problem, but everything else. What do you think? Btw, I'm also getting a trailing slash on folder links, but not if it's `site.com/something-else`. I guess that the solution would be removing the DirectorySlash, but will also break homepage, am I right?

Comment: `DirectorySlash` must be on otherwise it is a security issue. I have tested it and it worked for me. Which URL gave you 404?

Comment: The folder pages. `site.com/docs`, `site.com/releases` and `site.com/pages`. Everything else works fine. The index, all the `site.com/fakefolders` and every subpages of folders. Also I tired to remove `DirectorySlash` and everything works just fine, but then my second issue comes back.

Comment: Strangely `site.com/docs` is not causing 404 for me as it becomes `site.com/docs/` first and then displays content of `site.com/index.php?doc=`

Comment: Also check my update to test with `DirectorySlash Off`

Comment: Oh, my bad! It was my code that was forcing a 404. I wasn't checking the output of `$_GET`. But even if corrected, it should trigger the last RewriteRule and get `site.com/index.php?page=docs`. The `doc` should only be used when is `site.com/docs/something`. The index of docs should trigger `page`.

Comment: Due to `DirectorySlash On` a URL of `site.com/doc` becomes `site.com/doc/` and hence `RewriteRule ^docs/(.*)$ index.php?doc=$1 [L]` rule triggers.

Comment: Also, I forgot to say that all 404 errors are triggered via PHP's `header()`. It checks if a file exists in the folder. If not, then gives 404. (eg. `site.com/docs/something` will call `docs/something.php`. If file doesn't exists, then 404.)

Comment: Still no. I've been testing all our possible solutions we've been talking about, and I still think that the .htaccess I provided in thread continues to be the solution that gives me less issues, actually just one, which is the 403 error if I go to `site.com` without the trailing slash (or a directory listing if I remove `-Indexes`). Everything else is perfect. Even the 3 directories matches the RewriteRule for `?page=` and also don't create a trailing slash, which is what I want.

Comment: You seem to have made it way more complicated than it is required. I provided you a working and fully tested solution which works without any code messing it up. Good luck.